# Redis timeseries with python : ResponseError: unknown command 'TS.CREATE'

Tags: python, redis, redistimeseries

I am trying to create a timeseries in Redis using python like so:

```
    import redis
    connection_redis = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
    connection_redis.ts().create('ts', retention_msecs=0)
```

but I get the following error: ResponseError: unknown command 'TS.CREATE'.

I have been searching for a way to solve this problem but I haven't found anything.
I am running redis in a docker.

Thank you :)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Redis docker image does not contain any Redis module.

You can use the [Redis Stack](https://redis.io/docs/stack/) [docker image](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/install/docker/).

`redis/redis-stack-server` contains the RediSearch, RedisJSON, RedisGraph, RedisTimeSeries, and RedisBloom modules. `redis/redis-stack` also contains
[RedisInsight](https://redis.io/docs/stack/insight/).